# Moving a Range after pasting

Tags: excel, vba

So I am looking to have a button that on clicking copies and pastes a range from one sheet to another and on subsequent clicks the data would be pasted with out overwriting the data from the previous paste. I've written this code so far but I'm stuck on how to change where data would be pasted.

```
  Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Static cnt As Long
    cnt = cnt + 1
    Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "I have been clicked " & cnt & " times"
    Worksheets("Main").Range("A1:J13").Copy
    Worksheets("Secondary").Range("A1:J13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Secondary").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End( _
    xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Assuming there's always a value in ColA for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Worksheets("Secondary").Range("A1:J13").Offset(cnt*Range("A1:J13").Columns.count,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

or

```
Worksheets("Secondary").Range("A1:J13").Offset(0,cnt*14).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```